# Turn compound conditions on/off

Tags: pine-script

I'm able to add multiple conditions into one signal, but because of my lack of experience programming I can't figure out how could I toggle on/off different conditions in the options.

IncludeC1 = input(true)

IncludeC2 = input(false)

Condition 1 = crossover

Condition 2 = hull direction

Signal = crossover and hull direction

I would need to achieve this
Signal = crossover and (hull (if selected))

Basically so I can add, remove single conditions in the input section.

```
BoxCrossover = ta.crossover(close, boxHigh)
BoxCrossunder = ta.crossunder(close, boxLow)

hull_green = hullma > hullma[1]
hull_red = hullma < hullma[1]

Buy = BoxCrossover and hull_green
Sell = BoxCrossunder and hull_red
```

I tried if functions but I can't manage to make it work. Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Ternary Conditional Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D).

Something like that

```
i_hullOnOff = input.bool(true, 'Hull On/Off')

hull_green = hullma > hullma[1]

Buy = BoxCrossover and (i_hullOnOff ? hull_green : true)
```

Comment: You made my day Gustavo! It did the trick. Thank you very much for your kindness and support! Much appreciated.